# How should conditional variables in producer-consumer implementations be initialized

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to understand the use of conditional variables to implement producer-consumer buffers. I have the following code, which implements a queue for integers (which could be linux file descriptors). The code works as expected, but I am trying to understand why. Both enqueue and dequeue operations wait on some conditional variable before signaling the other conditional variable. Why are these waits unblocking? Is this due to spurious wakeups?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class FDQueue
{
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _notEmptyCv, _notFullCv;
    std::list<int> _fds;
    size_t _maxSize;

public:
    void add(int fd) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(this->_mutex);
        this->_notFullCv.wait(locker, [this](){return this->_fds.size() < this->_maxSize;});
        cout<<"Enqueue "<<endl;
        this->_fds.push_back(fd);
        locker.unlock();
        this->_notEmptyCv.notify_one();
    }

    int remove() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(_mutex);
        this->_notEmptyCv.wait(locker, [this](){return this->_fds.size() > 0;});
        int fd = this->_fds.front();
        this->_fds.pop_front();
        cout<<"Dequeue"<<endl;
        locker.unlock();
        this->_notFullCv.notify_all();
        return fd;
    }

    FDQueue(size_t maxSize) : _maxSize(maxSize) {}
};

FDQueue queue(5);

void producer() {
    while (true) {
        queue.add(0);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    }
}
void consumer() {
    while (true) {
        queue.remove();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(producer);
    std::thread t2(consumer);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use lock-free queue from [boost lock-free](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/lockfree.html) or [libcdc](https://github.com/khizmax/libcds). 2. "waits unblocking" - why do you think this code is "unblocking", remove you'r hack  `std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);` and check the code without it.

Comment: why is the `add` waiting? it should just `produce`

Comment: You can use [boost single-writer/single-reader fifo queue](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html) BTW

Comment: I understand there may be alternatives. What I am trying to do is understand why this is working. The code runs fine without the 2 second sleep in the producer. The reason `add` is waiting is to prevent queue overflow (the queue is limited to 5 entries).

Comment: You state `"What I am trying to do is understand why this is working"`.  Can you clarify exactly why you think it *shouldn't* work.  Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: `add` waits on `_notFullCv`, and `remove` waits on `_notEmptyCv`. How do these conditional variables get signaled for the very first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> add waits on _notFullCv, and remove waits on _notEmptyCv. How do these
>   conditional variables get signaled for the very first time?

They don't.  If you look at the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait), the overload of `std::condition_variable::wait` that accepts a lock `l` and predicate `pred` is effectively implemented as...

```
while (!pred())
  wait(l);
```

The important part in your case being that the condition is checked *before* waiting.  Hence, the first call to `add` will find the queue not full and no call to `std::condition_variable::wait` (without a predicate) will be made.