# std::condition_variable checks the condition for the first time, or do you have to wait for someone to make a notify?

Tags: c++, condition-variable

std::condition_variable checks the condition for the first time, or do you have to wait for someone to make a notify?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should conditional variables in producer-consumer implementations be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672365/how-should-conditional-variables-in-producer-consumer-implementations-be-initial)

Comment: What condition? Do you mean the predicate? What first time? Can you please clarify, maybe with some code?

Answer (score 5):

This is answered by reading [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait).

It's like:

```
while (!pred()) {
    wait(lock);
}
```

So, the condition is checked *first*.

This can also be shown by testing it (though, to be fair, it's hard to know just from that whether the results are deterministic).

Comment: Although, interestingly, [the `wait()` article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) has a code example that suggests `pred()` is checked first. Am I wrong?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah, so, the second set of numbered bullets on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable are wrong?

Comment: That part could probably be improved. It doesn't account for when the condition is already met. If the condition is met and you `wait` anyway you probably missed a `notify`. If it's a one-off event or the last event then it could `wait` forever.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say that it could be tested. Learning by trial is not practical in C++ because of Undefined Behavior, much less so with multi threading. What you observe isn't necessarily deterministic or reliable if you break rules you might not be aware of.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux As a very general rule, sure, but a simple condition variable with predicate, and no other thread notifying it, will show this behaviour in seconds. I myself often point out that some things in C++ have to be proven rather than simply tested-for, but that doesn't mean you can never test anything in the language. I would completely support a question that came to us with an observation (the observation in my answer) and asked whether it were well-defined/deterministic, of course! [tag:language-lawyer] is great fun, and I've contributed a lot to it from another account.

Comment: you can test to prove false (i.e. it doesn't do what is written in the tin), but you can't use test to prove true (i.e. it does what is written in the tin once doesn't mean it will always do it).

Comment: btw, [CPP standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.condition#condvar-13) supports your answer, so you don't need to test to prove :)

Comment: @SPD: Yeah, a quote from that is best ;) I am playing Halo simultaneously so no time for that lol. Feel free to edit it in if you're bored ;)